# How to send print to Windows XP?

Tags: server, windows, printing

Hello I am new to Ubuntu I had it for a month or two.

I am mad about figuring out a print server trying to send the print jobs that are coming to my print server to the windows XP machine by the network.

Can some one please help? I am a novice Ubuntu user.

Comment: Please be a little more clear? do you have the printer attached to the ubuntu machine or the Windows XP machine?

Comment: I have the printer hocked up to my xp and all the print pages go to my ubuntu and i want to send all of those print jobs to the xp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the printer by using a simple procedure with the System/Administration/Printing exactly as you do in a Windows XP printer, but you can find several issues when trying to print to a certain type/model of printers. Which will get your Windows XP printing service stuck.

You can override this behavior by disabling bi-directional printing in the Windows XP printer's preferences.

[image]

Good luck!

Note: If this don't fit your needs please just ask and I will delete it. Thank you!

### Edit

[image]

Comment: @Geppettvs D' Constanzo ok i will try that

Comment: how do i disable bi-directional on the xp?

Comment: New image added. In USB's check the Spool Settings details.

Comment: do i have to connect the printer to the xp machine to add it to ubuntu?

Comment: Yeah, it would be great. I was understanding that your printer was connected to your XP machine.