# Why won't hp print driver print past a test page?

Tags: printing, hp

Why won't hp dj1000j110 printer print more than the test page? Job goes to print queue, flashes for a moment, then disappears and the printer does not print anything. Printer driver is hplip-3.11.3a.run. Install telemetry available upon request.

Answer (score 2):

Disabling bi-directional printing on your printer will fix this problem. Take a look at this: [How to send print to Windows XP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34974/how-to-get-ubuntu-to-send-print-jobs-to-windows-xp/35104#35104)

Even when this answer refers to Windows XP acting like a print server, the same rules applies to HP printers when connected to a Linux machine. Give it a try and please inform.

Good luck!

### Edit:

Additionally, take a look at [HPLIP (The HP Linux Imaging and Printing)](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html). This can help you but the majority of the HP's are working perfectly right out of the box, I insist that you may be experiencing bi-directional printing issues. Unfortunately I don't have an HP physically connected to my computer at this very moment in order to run a test. HPLIP can, however, help you.

Comment: I erased all of Windows on purpose while installing Ubuntu 9.10. So, Windows XP, or any other Windows distro does not exit.

Comment: Currently, I run Ubuntu 10.04, trying to get my HP printer to work. HP driver hplip-3.11.3a.run is installed. It printed a test page, but the system will not print anything else. The job shows up on job queue for all of 2 sec then flashes off the screen.

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide you with a link. I hope this help you.

Comment: Further tests of the software reveals that the printer is trying real hard to print but for some reason it just can't or won't.

Comment: The Document Print Status sheet shows jobs "Processing", "Completed", or "Aborted", --- yet,the computer does not print anything. The power cord and liaison cable hooking the printer to the computer are hooked in there solidly.

Comment: well, ken1943... as I mentioned in the past (probably in a different answer), I have faced this kind of behavior in HP printers, several models that includes lasers and inkjets. The job goes to the queue, and the printer shows a bit of activity which stops suddenly leaving the printer stuck and the only way to make it work again is disconnecting from the mains. The test page in certain models is something that can be achieved by a portion of code inserted in the firmware.

Comment: (continued...) the problem comes when the printer -as you mention- is trying to understand what the printing queue and service is trying to say. And you should look for a way to override the bi-directional printing in your hardware via a software or HPLIP. I feel bad because of I can't provide you with screenshots and a more detailed "how-to" because of I don't have an HP printer to connect in my computer. But tomorrow I will try to continue a research in order to provide you with a good tip. Meanwhile look forward to override the bi-directional printing and let's see what happen. Good luck!

Comment: new problem: machine prints now but keeps giving the following error msg: "/usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftoraster failed"

Comment: What are you using for printing your PDF? evince? web browser? which? If you are using google-chrome and/or chromium-browser try Firefox. chrome/chromium seems to have known problems to print PDF files. Addittionally, take a look into this anwer provided by @Ragnar123: http://askubuntu.com/questions/20642/whats-the-response-to-error-message-usr-lib-cups-filter-pdftoraster-failed, please inform.

Comment: machine does not function now, not even for a test page. I do not know what program prints my PDF file. Ragnar123 poses some interesting questions ... .